# Is more correct consulting images directory or database to count how many there are?

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to insert images into banner dynamically, and is now working correctly. I upload my images and insert on database name of image if there are no validotor errors.

But I'd like to ask you a question that came to my mind, and I'm not finding the answer.

To insert an image, I want to check if the image already exists and also if there are more than 5 images, 5 images because I just want the maximum of 5 images at time on banner.

Im doing this, consulting my directory folder when I save images, and not consulting database.

What do you think better in terms of performance? Or is it the same? Do you see any advantage like Im doing?

heres my code example:

```
extAlllowed = array('image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/gif');
$myDirectory = ../banner-images/;                   
if(in_array($img['type'][$i],$extAlllowed))
{
    $fi = new FilesystemIterator($myDirectory, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    echo iterator_count($fi);

    if(file_exists($myDirectory.$image))
      {
        echo'Image selected already exist';
      }

    else if(iterator_count($fi)>=5)
      {
        echo'You can have only 5 images at time in banner.';
      }
    else
      {
        uploadImage($img['tmp_name'][$i],$image,'2000',$myDirectory);
        $inseretBanner = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO banners (img) VALUES (:img)");  
        $inseretBanner->bindValue(':img', $image);
        $inseretBanner->execute();
        echo'Image inserted with sucess';
      }                                             
}
```

Comment: There are many factors so the only way to be sure is to try it both ways and time it. However, this is micro-optimisation and you're likely to find that the difference is not significant in the context you're operating. I'd worry about it if you think there's a real problem.

Comment: Sidenote: `extAlllowed` is missing a `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering having several image files it would be faster to maintain a counter in the database, that contains the current image amount. The FilesystemIterator will internally run over all files to count them, what can lead to poor performance. A simple query (for example: SELECT image_amount FROM users WHERE id = [your current user]) to a database will be faster in most cases.

If you do so, you have to update the counter each time you insert/delete an image in the database.

Hope that helps.